# Swift 2 How can I make app keep executing code while not on screen?

Tags: swift2, background-process

App begins a thread when the "Run" button is tapped.  When switching to another app or the home screen, how do I allow the running task in the background?

Comment: Did you search for the answer?

Comment: Yes. Everything that came up for me either shows in obj-c or is pre 6/16 so a lot of the deprecated. I'm assuming you are asking because you have found something or know how?